# Output reason for Python crash

Tags: python, multithreading

I have an application which polls a bunch of servers every few minutes. To do this, it spawns one thread per server to poll (15 servers) and writes back the data to an object:

```
import requests

class ServerResults(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.results = []

    def add_server(some_argument):
        self.results.append(some_argument)

servers = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2']
results = ServerResults()

for s in servers:
    t = CallThreads(poll_server, s, results)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

def poll_server(server, results):
    response = requests.get(server, timeout=10)
    results.add_server(response.status_code);
```

The `CallThreads` class is a helper function to call a function (in this case `poll_server()` with arguments (in this case `s` and `results`), you can see the source at my Github repo of [Python utility functions](https://github.com/dotancohen/pytility/blob/master/util.py). Most of the time this works fine, however *sometimes* a thread intermittently hangs. I'm not sure why, since I am using a timeout on the GET request. In any case, if the thread hangs then the hung threads build up over the course of hours or days, and then Python crashes:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 495, in start
    _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread

Exception in thread Thread-575 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)
Exception in thread Thread-1671 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)
Exception in thread Thread-831 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)
```

How might I deal with this? There seems to be no way to [kill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) [a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11431637/how-can-i-kill-a-thread-in-python) [blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680589/python-threading-thread-can-be-stopped-only-with-private-method-self-thread-st) [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564137/python-how-to-terminate-a-thread-when-main-program-ends) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682249/how-to-terminate-a-thread-in-python-without-loop-in-run-method) [Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635080/terminate-a-multi-thread-python-program). This application needs to run on a Raspberry Pi, so large libraries such as [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) won't fit, in fact I need to get rid of the [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) library as well!

Comment: Firstly, is this on a pi when it hangs, or are you testing elsewhere? There may be platform-specific tools that would help see what the thread is doing, but you haven't specified your platform.

Comment: Secondly, what is `requests`? Without seeing that, it's impossible to say if there's a race condition in there

Comment: Thirdly, even if you don't use twisted, synchronous non-blocking I/O in a single thread is much more scalable than this

Comment: Thank you Useless. On the Raspberry Pi the application runs for a day or two, then crashes. On a Kubuntu desktop it runs for at least a few days, but starts consuming large amounts of memory, on the order of a few GiB (RSS). I added a link to the [Python-Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/) library in the question.

Comment: Killing the threads is a terrible idea (really, it can leave stuff in a bad state). If the process bloats on Kubuntu, you can attach gdb and get a stack trace for each thread - you should be able to confirm what was happening when it hung. If it's blocked in `read` or `recv`, you can close the fd and detach to see if it recovers.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at gdb. The issue is that only a small portion of threads start hanging (on the order of 1%) so I do need a lot of 'luck' to catch a hung one. Have you any tips in that regard? Thank you!

Comment: Once it's hung, it should stay hung and stick around ...

Comment: Thanks, I've been googling and found some good info, but I do see that I'll need quite a bit of practice before I become even close to being able to debug the hangs. What does it mean to "close the fd and detach to see if it recovers"? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, a *possible* scenario is that when a thread "hangs" for one given server, it will stay there "forever". Next time you query your servers another thread is spawned (`_start_new_thread`), up to the point where Python crashes.

Probably not your (main) problem, but you should:

- use a thread pool - this won't stress the limited resources of your your system as much as spawning *new* threads again and again.
- check that you use a "thread-compatible" mechanism to handle concurrent access to `results`. Maybe a [`semaphore`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#semaphore-objects) or [`mutex`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html#module-mutex) to *lock* atomic portions of your code. Probably better would be a dedicated data structure such as a [`queue`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#module-Queue).

---

Concerning the "hang" *per se* -- beware that the *timeout* argument while "opening a URL" ([urlopen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen)) is related to the time-out for establishing the connection. Not for downloading the actual data:

> The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for
>   blocking operations like the connection attempt (if not specified, the
>   global default timeout setting will be used). This actually only works
>   for HTTP, HTTPS and FTP connections.

Comment: Thank you. Actually, I am aware that the timeout is only for the connection, `requests` does not seem to expose a way to timeout the download. I like the idea of one thread per server, but when the thread hangs, then the server in question will no longer be polled.

Comment: @dotancohen Neither urllib2 not requests expose the socket object I think. So, you probably have to [socket.setdefaulttimeout](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.setdefaulttimeout) to fix I/O operation timeout *just before* opening your connection (and probably resetting it afterward). Concerning the use of a thread pool, my *guess* was when a server block an incoming request from a thread it will block all subsequent attempts to connect. but maybe threads hangs "at random"?

Comment: Thank you Sylvain, I'll take a look at the socket timeout. Nice find! The servers do allow subsequent connections, otherwise the following threads would fail to poll them. I really don't know what causes the hangup or even where to begin to debug it.

Comment: @dotancohen "where to begin to debug it" have you tried to capture network traffic using a tool like WireShark. In order to see if the connection was established properly for example.

Comment: Actually, I haven't. I was hoping to stay in Python, as the last time I tried to use WireShark (actually, it was etheral the time) it was a complete pain. I do realize that it has matured much since then, though. I was planning on using pdb to see which code is run, and then placing debug print statements and seeing where the trail leaves off. Primitive, I know! I just haven't gotten to it yet, and I won't get to it if I can just kill these threads. A missing poll occasionally would not be a problem.